# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in my code

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following error in the code:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'introducido' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `cars` (`introducido`, `modelo`, `producido_en`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, sdfsdf, ?, 2019-06-03 08:18:17, 2019-06-03 08:18:17))

And I do not know how to solve, I leave my code:

**CarController.php**

```php
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Car;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class CarController extends Controller
{
    public function crear(Request $request){

        $introducido= $request['introducido'];

        $modelo=$request['modelo'];

        $producido_en=$request['producido_en'];

        $car=new Car();

        $car->introducido=$introducido;

        $car->modelo=$modelo;

        $car->producido_en=$producido_en;

        $car-> save ();

        return redirect ()->b ack();
    }


    public function mostrar(){

    }
}
```

**Index-blade**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Aplicacion de autos</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6"></div>

                <form action="{{route('cars.crear')}}" method="post">

                   @csrf

                    <div class="row form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <label for="">Introducir:</label>

                            <input type="text" name="introducir" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <label for="">Modelo:</label>

                            <input type="text" name="modelo" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <label for="">Producido_en:</label>

                            <input type="date" name="producido-en" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <button type="submit" class="btm btm-success w-50 float-right">Crear</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>

            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

                    <tr>

                        <th>Introducir</th>

                        <th>Modelo</th>

                        <th>Producido_en</th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td></td>

                        <td></td>

                        <td></td>

                </table>     

            </div> 

    </div>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: introducido  in some parts of your code  introducir in others what does the table definition say?

Comment: Can you show the table migration for `cars`?

Comment: When you googled your error message with & without your names, strings & data and you checked all the many answers, what did you find? See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all check your migration. Maybe it's because of a typo or
  something like that.
- Then check your model. You should include "introducido" in your $fillable field.

Comment: In this case introducido does not need to be fillable as they are not using [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) (create or fill).

Comment: @RyanJField You're right; but when you want to use Model for inserting or updating, you must define the $fillable field. If you don't define that, you cannot use: $car=new Car();
$car->introducido=$introducido;
$car->modelo=$modelo;
$car->producido_en=$producido_en;
$car-> save ();

Comment: I mean by using save() function on the model, nothing will be inserted if the field doesn't exist in fillable array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your cars table in db does not have "introducido" column.

**Solutions**
 - Please check migration file for cars and check it is migrated successfully.
 - If you still face issue then please check "introducido" column is added in $fillable in "Car" model.

Answer (score 0):

Your Car model must be with columns in fillable

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cars';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = ['introducido', 'modelo', 'producido_en'];
}
```

In controller:

```
use App\Car;

public function crear(Request $request){

        $post = $request->all();

        Car::create($post);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```